# asp.net 4.0 "Page Not Found" error occured while Uploading File

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm unable to resolve Error for Page Not Found while uploading any file sized > 1KB.

The sample code used

```
 <input id="UploadExcel" type="file" size="48" name="UploadExcel1" class="Browser" runat="server" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="SaveButton" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

  protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      // page not found occurred.
  }
```

web.config settings

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100" />
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="50000000" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

The Error occurred when page is PostBack with event defined on upload button i.e "btnUpload_Click".
I've tried the same with removing Click event on upload button but still the same error.
I'm just wondering, in upload button event their is not code specified for uploading file or saving file,then why such error?

I'm thinking their might me server related setting to make it work.Since the same is working properly in localhost environment.

Any idea of Server IIS level setting ?

Comment: Please write detailed description this problem.(screenshot, code sample, etc.)

Comment: @rootturk detail description added please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try your code on my solution.

Web.Config File :

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="3600" maxRequestLength="1048576"  />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<security>
  <requestFiltering>                        
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Aspx.cs Code:

```
        protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = UploadExcel.PostedFile;
    }
```

Aspx Code :

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server" >
    <div>
        <input id="UploadExcel" type="file" size="48" name="UploadExcel1" class="Browser" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="SaveButton" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
   </div>
</form>
```

Please check your Web.Config code so your httpRuntime tag out to `<system.web>` tag. My code is working perfectly. (try to 550 MB files)

Please check S.S.
[image]

**Please check your file succesfull working and file-size, and check your IIS MİME/TYPE List.**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, the same code is working fine in local host but not in server when the page it is hosted

Comment: Ok I Understand your problem.I change my webconfig file  check and try please.

Comment: Thanks for the detail explanation.But Still I'm facing the same error. I've testing with DBF file which is working properly but not with excel ,txt or zip file.Is there any server configuration need for excel ..?

Comment: No problem, please check your file size and successfully working. I'm add two screenshot in my answer, please check your IIS Mime Types list, and check your file. if you do not get a result, please share your file, I try my IIS Server.

Comment: IIS MIME excel (.xls) was missing.Added the same and now the FileUpload is working properly.Thanks a lot rootturk !